# Disabling Cleanup in a Spring-Kafka Streams application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

The default of Spring-Kafka is to cleanup local state maintained on the filesystem when a Kafka-Streams application is stopped. It seems like this is governed by `CleanupConfig` passed to the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`.

I tried to disable this as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class App {

  public final static String STORE_NAME = "store";
  public static final String INPUT_TOPIC = "input";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder(KafkaStreamsConfiguration streamsConfig) {
    return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfig, new CleanupConfig(false, false));
  }

  @Bean
  public KTable<String, Integer> kTable(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
    return kStreamBuilder.table(
            INPUT_TOPIC,
            Consumed.with(new Serdes.StringSerde(), new Serdes.IntegerSerde()),
            Materialized.as(STORE_NAME)
    );
  }

}
```

Still, when the application is stopped, all state in `/tmp/kafka-streams/` is deleted. Any idea how this should be done correctly?